# MLSeq package error

Tags: r, bioconductor

I would like to use MLSeq package but I am getting this error.

> library(MLSeq)
>   Error : object ‘bag.default’ is not exported by 'namespace:caret'
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘MLSeq’

How can I overcome this error?

> sessionInfo() R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit) Running under: OS X 10.12.1 (Sierra)

Output:

> locale: [1]
>   en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages: [1] parallel  stats4    stats     graphics 
>   grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:  [1] edgeR_3.14.0
>   randomForest_4.6-12        limma_3.28.21              DESeq2_1.12.4
>   SummarizedExperiment_1.2.3 Biobase_2.32.0
>   GenomicRanges_1.24.3        [8] GenomeInfoDb_1.8.7
>   IRanges_2.6.1              S4Vectors_0.10.3
>   BiocGenerics_0.18.0        caret_6.0-72               ggplot2_2.1.0
>   lattice_0.20-34
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_0.12.7
>   locfit_1.5-9.1       digest_0.6.10        foreach_1.4.3
>   plyr_1.8.4           chron_2.3-47         acepack_1.4.1
>   MatrixModels_0.4-1   RSQLite_1.0.0        [10] zlibbioc_1.18.0
>   minqa_1.2.4          data.table_1.9.6     annotate_1.50.1
>   SparseM_1.72         car_2.1-3            nloptr_1.0.4
>   rpart_4.1-10         Matrix_1.2-7.1       [19] splines_3.3.1
>   lme4_1.1-12          BiocParallel_1.6.6   geneplotter_1.50.0
>   stringr_1.1.0        foreign_0.8-67       RCurl_1.95-4.8
>   munsell_0.4.3        mgcv_1.8-15          [28] htmltools_0.3.5
>   nnet_7.3-12          gridExtra_2.2.1      htmlTable_1.7
>   Hmisc_4.0-0          codetools_0.2-15     XML_3.98-1.4
>   MASS_7.3-45          bitops_1.0-6         [37] ModelMetrics_1.1.0
>   grid_3.3.1           nlme_3.1-128         xtable_1.8-2
>   gtable_0.2.0         DBI_0.5-1            magrittr_1.5
>   scales_0.4.0         stringi_1.1.2        [46] XVector_0.12.1
>   reshape2_1.4.2       genefilter_1.54.2    latticeExtra_0.6-28 
>   Formula_1.2-1        RColorBrewer_1.1-2   iterators_1.0.8
>   tools_3.3.1          pbkrtest_0.4-6       [55] survival_2.40-1
>   AnnotationDbi_1.34.4 colorspace_1.2-7     cluster_2.0.5
>   knitr_1.14           quantreg_5.29

Answer (score 1):

The error arises from importing "bag.default" function in caret. NAMESPACE is fixed in the development version 1.15.1. You can download the source files from https://github.com/Bioconductor-mirror/MLSeq. With the upcoming version 1.16.0, namespace error will be fixed in the released version.